# Pandas calculating difference between dates and getting a very large number

Tags: pandas, date

So I have a table with a date column (example below)

| Date1 |
| --- |
| 2020-11-08 |
| 2020-12-03 |
| 2020-11-21 |

I am trying to calculate the difference between the column and a specific date with the following code:

```
df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime('2020-12-31') - df['DELDATED']
```

I wanted to get a number of days difference, however I obtained the following:

| diff |
| --- |
| 454579200000000000 |
| 2419200000000000 |
| 3456000000000000 |

Why am I getting this and how can I get what I anticipate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df['diff'] = (pd.to_datetime('2020-12-31') - df['DELDATED']).dt.days
```

Working same like [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html) for subtract from right side, but less clear in my opinion:

```
df['diff'] = df['DELDATED'].rsub(pd.to_datetime('2020-12-31')).dt.days
```